# Fixed Income portfolio type

Tags: fixed-income, portfolio-management, portfolio-optimization, minimum-variance, risk-parity

Could someone kindly point me toward a primer that would cover the various type of fixed income portfolio strategies under modern portfolio theory ?

In a nutshell, I would like to know what kind of portfolio is there beyond minimum var, maximum diversification, risk-parity and equal-weight ?